# Adding jpanel to my frame wont work

Tags: javascript, java, jframe, jpanel

I am creating a simple java game and I am pretty new to this. My problem is that i've created objects and a player for my game that i want to add to the screen. What I've done is that I've added these objects to one JPanel that I later add on the frame. What only shows up are my objects but the player does not show up. Ive tried creating two seperate jpanels that i add on the frame, but that does not work either

```
public GameViewer(Board b) {
        PlayerPiece player = new PlayerPiece();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(player);
        panel.addKeyListener(player);
        panel.add(new GameComponent(b));

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //background image// frame.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER); ****
        frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

more imports *

```
      public class PlayerPiece extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
     Timer playTimer = new Timer(5,this);
     int positionX = 150, positionY = 360, speedX = 0, speedY = 0;

     public PlayerPiece(){
          playTimer.start();
         addKeyListener(this);
         setFocusable(true); 
         setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.fillRect(positionX, positionY,50,30);
     }

       Further on I only have keyevents
```

@Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
          if (positionX < 0){ //If the player is outside of the frame stop it
              speedX = 0;
              positionX = 0;
    }

          if (positionX > 300){ //Right side but outside of the screen, block it
              speedX = 0;
              positionX = 300;
    }

          if (positionY < 0){
              speedY = 0;
              positionY = 0;
    }

          if (positionY > 360){
              speedY = 0;
              positionY = 360;
    }

          positionX = positionX + speedX;
          positionY = positionY + speedY;
          repaint();
}

@Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
          int keyCode = e.getKeyCode(); //Get the button pressed
              if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) { //Go Right
                  speedX = 2;
                  speedY = 0;
        }
              if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) { //Go Down
                  speedX = 0;
                  speedY = 2;
        }
              if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) { //Go Left
                  speedX = -2;
                  speedY = 0;
        }
              if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) { //Go up
                  speedX = 0;
                  speedY = -2;
        }
}

@Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                speedX = 0;
                speedY = 0;
}
@Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

  }
```

Comment: How does your PlayerPiece look like? Can you edit that?

Comment: I also think its something weird with my playerpiece, but i tried only adding the playerpiece directly on the frame and it shows up just fine. I have a paintComponent, keyevents and actionevents in it. But I cant just add it directly to the frame since i have other objects to display, and thats why I use JPanels

Comment: I added my playerpiece class now, if you want to look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what `PlayerPiece` was so I replaced it with a button. The code you posted should work so the problem must be in `PlayerPiece`.

So to fix it, replace `PlayerPiece` with another object like a Button and make sure the buttons shows up. Then look at your `PlayerPiece` class and find the problem there.

UPDATE: I think your problem is that the PlayerPiece (which is just another JPanel) shows outside of the frame. Try the below code and you'll see it does show up. I omitted the irrelevant parts of the code, such as event listeners.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        PlayerPiece player = new PlayerPiece();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(player);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(400,400);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayerPiece extends JPanel {
     int positionX = 150, positionY = 150;

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.fillRect(positionX, positionY,50,30);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah what you are doing makes much sense, I now edited my post and added my playerpiece class without the keyevents (movements) if you want to look at it and give some feedback. Because with the code written it should atleast show a rectangle

Comment: Hmm i tried your code and it does still not draw a red rectangle, maybe I need to call repaint somwhere?

Comment: You are right it works, if I don't add my other gameobjects to the jpanel.. maybe those are poorly written. Ty for your effort and time

Comment: I just realized I have 2 paint components in each of the classes

Comment: Well that explains it :)